# Como hacer un having en Python Pandas

Tags: mysql, python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select id_cliente,medio,sum(movies) AS películas 
FROM clientes 
GROUP BY id_cliente,medio
HAVING SUM(movies) > avg (movies)
```

**Como salida me da:**  por cliente, el medio que mas usa para ver películas

Lo que llevo en pandas:

`df =df_clientes.groupby(['id_cliente','medio']).agg({'movies': np.sum })`

**Como salida:** La suma de películas por medio de cada cliente.
Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo hacer en pandas para que esta suma sea mayor que el promedio tal como con el `having`?

Answer (score 0):

Tengo la sensación que la solución que buscas es:

```
dfg =df_clientes.groupby(['id_cliente','medio']).sum()['movies']
dfg[ dfg>dfg.mean() ]
```

Y que el SQL debería ser:

```
select id_cliente,medio,sum(movies) AS películas 
  FROM clientes 
  GROUP BY id_cliente,medio
  HAVING SUM(movies) > (
      SELECT AVG(peliculas) FROM (
          select id_cliente,medio,
            sum(movies) AS peliculas 
            FROM clientes 
            GROUP BY 1,2  
        ) c1  
    );
```

Tal y como lo propones, dado que la suma de unos valores siempre es mayor que su promedio, la condición del `HAVING` se cumplirá siempre, lo que equivale a no ponerlo.

Con mi propuesta, obtienes aquellos clientes por medio con películas por encima de la media de todos los clientes.

Espero haber respondido a tu pregunta.